# JavaScript - Rock Paper Scissors in console

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems getting my simple Rock Paper Scissors game to display the winner of each game when the user chooses anything either than Rock. How do I use multiple if...else statements so that my declareWinner  function works when the user chooses Scissors or Paper?

```
let choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

// GETTING USER INPUT
const userInput = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?").toLocaleLowerCase(); 
    if(userInput ==="paper" || userInput ==="rock" || userInput ==="scissors"){
        console.log("You chose " + `${userInput}`);
    } else {
        console.log("Error! Try again!");
    }

// GETTING COMPUTER INPUT
const computerInput = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]; 
console.log("Computer chose" + ` ${computerInput}`);

    if (computerInput <= 0.33) {
        computerInput = "rock";
    }
    if (computerInput >= 0.67) {
        computerInput = "paper";
    }
    if (computerInput >= 0.66) {
        computerInput = "scissors";
    }

// DECLARE WINNER 

// User Chooses Rock
function declareWinner(userInput, computerInput) {
    if(userInput === "rock" && computerInput === 'paper') {
        console.log ('You win! Rock beats paper!');     
    } else if (userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'rock') {
        console.log ('Its a tie!');     
    } else if (userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'scissors') {
        console.log ('You win! Rock beats scissors!');     
// User Chooses Paper
    } else if(userInput === "paper" && computerInput === 'rock') {
        console.log ('You win! Rock beats paper!');     
    } else if (userInput === 'paper' && computerInput === 'paper') {
        console.log ('Its a tie!');     
    } else if (userInput === 'paper' && computerInput === 'scissors') { 
        console.log ('You lose! Scissors beats paper!');  
// User Chooses Scissors
    } else if(userInput === "scissors" && computerInput === 'rock') {
        console.log ('You lose! Rock beats scissors!');     
    } else if (userInput === 'scissors' && computerInput === 'paper') {
        console.log ('You win! Scissors beats paper!');     
    } else  { 
        console.log ('It is a tie!');  
    }  
}

declareWinner();
```

Comment: Please could you add a working [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so we can see what's going on

Comment: You have labelled it as `const` - try a `var` instead?

Comment: Could you also include your declareWinner function so we can see what that does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two problems with the code:-

- You are doing `choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];` which results in a random value from `choices` array, so there is no need for multiple if-else statements that were after it.
- You were missing the `declareWinner` function declaration.

Also, You are missing some conditions in `declareWinner` function, like `userInput === 'paper' && computerInput === 'rock'`, `userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'scissors'` etc.

```js
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

// GETTING USER INPUT
const userInput = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
if (userInput === "paper" || userInput === "rock" || userInput === "scissors") {
  console.log("You chose " + `${userInput}`);
} else {
  console.log("Error! Try again!");
}

// GETTING COMPUTER INPUT
let computerInput = choices[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
console.log("Computer chose" + ` ${computerInput}`);

// DECLARE WINNER 
const winner = declareWinner(userInput, computerInput);

function declareWinner(userInput, computerInput) {
  if (userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'paper') {
    console.log('You lose! Rock beats Paper');
  } else if (userInput === 'scissors' && computerInput === 'paper') {
    console.log('You win! Scissors beats Paper');
  } else {
    console.log('You tie!');
  }
}
```

---

Tip:- You can use an object to choose the winner in `declareWinner` function.

```js
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

// GETTING USER INPUT
const userInput = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
if (userInput === "paper" || userInput === "rock" || userInput === "scissors") {
  console.log("You chose " + `${userInput}`);
} else {
  console.log("Error! Try again!");
}

// GETTING COMPUTER INPUT
let computerInput = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
console.log("Computer chose" + ` ${computerInput}`);

// DECLARE WINNER 
const winner = declareWinner(userInput, computerInput);

function declareWinner(userInput, computerInput) {
  let win = {
    rock: "scissors",
    paper: "rock",
    scissors: "paper"
  };

  if (win[userInput] === computerInput) {
    console.log(`You won! ${userInput} beats ${computerInput}`);
  } else if (win[computerInput] === userInput) {
    console.log(`You lost! ${computerInput} beats ${userInput}`);
  } else console.log("Tie")
}
```

Comment: I've added the declareWinner function and included the other conditions, however now it only works when the user choose rock.  For example if user chooses paper, the computer executes the declareWinner function and console logs ('You win! Rock beats scissors!') because it doesn't meet the other if conditions. Do I need to use a switch statement to evaluate when the user chooses the other options (Paper, Scissors)?

Comment: Switch statement would be another way of doing this, but again you need to use 2 if conditions for each case. Ex: In case user chooses `"rock"`, you need 2 ifs to check if `computerInput` is `"paper"` or `"scissors"`. I have included a better way of doing this using objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a const value. Use let instead:

```
let computerInput = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
```